Extract txt and tables from PDF & Word
I'm building an app which extracts text and tables from pdf and it's creating HTML from that. What is the best way to make sure I'm extracting the data in the same format from the PDF & Word document? Since currently for example I have an issue with one of the files which contain table which is spitted on 2 pages it's not extracting it right and in the HTML I can see the spacing it's not the same as original file.
I have tried to extract the tables using pdfplumber , for the most part but like I mention it's having issues with tables which are on 2 pages.

For PDFs a page is really a page, like a paper page. So in the PDF there isn't really a link between the two parts of the table on two pages. PDF is an output format, mainly for printing, based on PostScript. What you're trying to do is like using OCR software and expecting it to know that those two table parts belong together somehow. Word documents are a whole other ball game, of course, and it should be possible to output nice HTML. Your question should probably focus on one or the other, because they are not even similar.

I added the "python" tag for you, which I guessed is the programming language you're using? Without it your question won't reach the people who can possibly answer it.

I want to reinforce what KIKO said.  PDF was never designed to be a data source.  It just has "put the letter X here, now put the letter Y there".  There is no structure inside a PDF document -- no words, no paragraphs, no tables, no lists.  It's just a list of letters and locations.  The converters do the best they can to recreate what the human sees, but it's never going to be perfect.

So maybe convert the pdf into word and then extract? That would give me better result then extracting directly the pdf? Do you have a suggestion for good method to extract text, tables and format from word document.

The PDF format is based on a fixed layout and lacks any logical or semantic structure. While a visually formatted document might appear to have a clear organisation into headings, paragraphs and tables, this structure is mostly not explicitly represented in the PDF's internal data hierarchy.
Unlike HTML or Word documents, there is nothing internally in the PDF file which indicates a table is present. It is just text organised by physical x,y locations on the document which "looks" like a table. This makes it very difficult for any library -- Pdfplumber, Camelot, Tabula, Pdftables, Pdf-table-extract etc to extract tables 100% right all the time. They use various techniques like rules based, computer vision, machine learning or a combination of those to extract tables from PDFs. When tables in PDFs overflow over to the next page, it makes it even harder as there might be page headers, page numbers or watermarks which occur before the table continues.
Converting PDF to Word and then trying extraction will also not work for the same reason. The convertor will not know that it is a table it is extracting before it can be recreated as "table" in Word.
There are two solutions which work remarkable well from my experience:

High quality OCR software. I have seen success with Azure's document intelligence.
Extract the text in a layout preserving manner and then pass the text to a LLM to extract tables. This works well with GPT4 and Gemini Pro.

But both the approaches need you to send data to a 3rd party.

Extract the text in a layout preserving manner and then pass the text to a LLM to extract tables. This works well with GPT4 and Gemini Pro.
I'm already doing that to translate the passed text I mean if i extract the text how LLM will know where should be a table?

@Shwapx it's the magic of LLMs. I guess they were trained with enough data with tables in them. But you need to provide the input text in layout preserved mode. By layout preserving, I mean the text extracted should have the same structure as the original PDF. Disclaimer for following link : I am a co-founder and architect for this product. You can use this extractor to extract text from PDF (it uses layout preserving mode by default). Take that text (with tables) and ask ChatGPT to extract the tables.

Do you think i can achieve that with any python library?

pdfplumber has an option to extract text lines. They do mark it as an experimental feature. It works but it has (or had) its limitations.

And what do you use for prompting even if i get the extracted text in layout preserve mode and pass it to OpenAI it give me document in simple form without layout preserve?

A prompt like this: Please extract all the tables from the given context. The format of the extracted tables should be in CSV format. \n\nThe context:\n[paste document contents in layout preserved mode]\n\nTables:\n
